# create à label based on conditions

Tags: pandas, numpy, label, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I want to assign a label for my dataset based on two conditions

```
dataset['Class'] = np.where(dataset['Motor Frequency (Hz)']>=30 & dataset['FCW Status']=6, 'Normal', 'Anomaly')
```

but I got this error :
cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: you're missing a `=` needs to be `dataset['FCW Status']==6`

Comment: same it aint works..

Comment: You also need to enclose your conditions with parentheses `()` due to operator precedence

Answer (score 1):

I think need add `()` to conditions due to operator precedence and change `=` to `==`:

```
dataset['Class'] = np.where((dataset['Motor Frequency (Hz)']>=30)&(dataset['FCW Status']==6), 
                            'Normal', 'Anomaly')
```